# SegWit, Bitcoin JSON-RPC and (strange?) addresses

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, segregated-witness

I'm trying to analyse this transaction:

https://blockchain.info/tx/a388d6f88373aacf2a5c170eeff4adf51f2c6744da26375d5890f42d653a2e6c

I used to be able to just run `bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction txid 1` and get a reasonable output, but running it with this particular transaction id, I get this:

```
{
  "txid": "a388d6f88373aacf2a5c170eeff4adf51f2c6744da26375d5890f42d653a2e6c",
  "hash": "c856582f997dc4b6f1e009f2096c4e549aeaeeb3f20703dbd71476dc957f77ec",
  "version": 1,
  "size": 383,
  "vsize": 192,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "37138d3df8e1d41bf6474ecdc21d53f78ab9907c500172de31bda4048556bd83",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "",
        "hex": ""
      },
      "txinwitness": [
        "",
        "304402205ed1d5ac8bee5f58da52cdf6fe6e64dccd9560c84ae933172ad26ae1fd7468eb02201e5db99e00d7fd3997b2b457c4b689c1cd8b2708afa128d030fc62055117d07401",
        "3045022100fa5054964962656890e466b35f111ab5b2f869eb41c39a6830bde9b7f00013b00220592d5369b295ec49e90504060748a67cc371519ab945fbcbb9e99b5b1d8040dc01",
        "52210375e00eb72e29da82b89367947f29ef34afb75e8654f6ea368e0acdfd92976b7c2103a1b26313f430c4b15bb1fdce663207659d8cac749a0e53d70eff01874496feff2103c96d495bfdd5ba4145e3e046fee45e84a8a48ad05bd8dbb395c011a32cf9f88053ae"
      ],
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.08000000,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 04645ed4e7b22362e4baf1aa396115450d99347c OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a91404645ed4e7b22362e4baf1aa396115450d99347c88ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "1QDwdPsF1cpf6Wvmo8QmFWZKUVGh1KzNh"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 0.01043487,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0 701a8d401c84fb13e6baf169d59684e17abd9fa216c8cc5b9fc63d622ff8c58d",
        "hex": "0020701a8d401c84fb13e6baf169d59684e17abd9fa216c8cc5b9fc63d622ff8c58d",
        "type": "witness_v0_scripthash"
      }
    }
  ],
  "hex": "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",
  "blockhash": "000000000000000000e8b63e15371848d765904e3bcfee1d0b45a37247fca9c2",
  "confirmations": 7,
  "time": 1507561656,
  "blocktime": 1507561656
}
```

So, there are no addresses in the second output. But blockchain.info has this to say:

```
bc1qwqdg6squsna38e46795at95yu9atm8azzmyvckulcc7kytlcckxswvvzej (0.09083487 BTC - Output) --> 1QDwdPsF1cpf6Wvmo8QmFWZKUVGh1KzNh - (Unspent) 0.08 BTC, 
bc1qwqdg6squsna38e46795at95yu9atm8azzmyvckulcc7kytlcckxswvvzej - (Unspent) 0.01043487 BTC
```

I have multiple questions:

1. In the above blockchain.info link I gave, what are those strange-looking addresses starting with "bc1...", and
2. Is there a way to extract such data from the output of `getrawtransaction`?
3. If not, how did blockchain.info did it?

Comment: Search about "Bech32 address format": https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki Bech32 is a way to write SegWit addresses

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed it! Any clue how to get it from bitcoind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the above blockchain.info link I gave, what are those strange-looking addresses starting with "bc1...", and

Those are bech32 addresses. These are specified in [BIP 173](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki)

> Is there a way to extract such data from the output of getrawtransaction?

No. The latest release of Bitcoin Core does not have functionality for converting native witness outputs into bech32 addresses. However blockchain.info does so they are displaying those outputs as bech32 addresses. Bech32 functionality in Bitcoin Core will be released in Bitcoin Core 0.15.1 along with segwit wallet functionality.

> If not, how did blockchain.info did it?

Blockchain.info does not use Bitcoin Core. They have their own custom software and it seems that they have implemented bech32.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a bech32 address you need to start from the hrp (prefix, determines mainnet or testnet), witness version, redeem script and pass them to a segwit bech32 encoder.

https://github.com/Samourai-Wallet/samourai-wallet-android/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/samourai/wallet/segwit/bech32/SegwitAddress.java#L48

More bech32 code can be found here: https://github.com/sipa/bech32